# Convert actual time to float in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, time

How can I convert a specific time or actual time, in SQL, to a float number? E.g., if it is 09:59:57 AM I want this float number: 0.416634556 like it is in Excel. 
Thank you all.

Comment: I try this with success: `CAST(GETDATE()-CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS FLOAT)`. There is a simpliest way?

Answer (score 2):

take a look at this, you may find your answer here: [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(DATETIME, Col1) AS FLOAT) AS NewValue
FROM Table1
```

Comment: Result: `Error converting data type varchar to float.`

Comment: With change `VARCHAR` to `DATETIME` it's almost there, but I just want de decimal part.

Comment: @PJLG try this SELECT CAST(CONVERT(DATETIME, Col1) AS FLOAT) AS NewValue FROM Table1

Comment: that is what I'm going to say, just having problem with the internet :D

Comment: @PJLG use decimal instead of float something like `SELECT CAST(CONVERT(DATETIME, Col1) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS NewValue FROM Table1`

Comment: You still have the integer part and only have two decimals digits. I want 0 as integer part and all digits of decimal part. Probably the best way is how I commented in my question: `CAST(GETDATE()-CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS FLOAT)`

Answer (score 1):

None of the other answers worked for me, but this does:    `SELECT CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATETIME) AS FLOAT) - FLOOR(CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATETIME) AS FLOAT))` And then you can swap out the `GETDATE()` calls for your column.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT CAST(cast(Col1 as datetime) AS FLOAT) - CAST(cast(Col1 as datetime) AS int) AS decPart
FROM yourTable

try this one